# How can I see all the differences between two python conda environments?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

I have one environment that somehow works but I can’t manually recreate it. I can clone it, and the cloned env works also, but if I try to set up a new env by installing the packages manually it doesn’t work.

Working env is somehow linked to the package installed with the brew but when I look at python search paths, there isn’t any listed path that searches in the folder where that package is installed.

What would be the best way to debug this?

Comment: Virtualenv1: `conda list | sort > list1`  Virtualenv2: `conda list | sort > list2` `diff list1 list2` Did you try basic command line utilities such as sort and unique? You can compare installed packages

Comment: @user1462442 thank you for your comment! When I look installed packages with *pip freeze* they are the same but when I use *conda list | sort >* I see some differences. Problem seems to be in the difference between *pip install* and *conda install* for pyobject. 

When I use *pip instal*l I have reference to the package installed with brew but with *conda install* that is not the case. Do you know maybe how can I fix that?

Comment: I kinda avoid conda because my experience with their dependency resolver isn't great.

I would look at the dependencies within your application and manually test each depency until your application works. Since you view differences with conda, you can take your time to specify your requirements.txt to avoid this issue in the future.

Use `python3 -m venv venv; source venv/bin/activate` to create your own env testbed

Comment: Thanks once again @user1462442, I will do that.